# Execute Process Task Bpmbs

Tags: sql-server, ssis, executeprocesstask

I have an SSIS package that reads from a spreadsheet and writes out to a CSV file. I also need to have a header record as the first record with the number of records that were processed. I have the 2 data flows to create the output file (,csv) and the header record (.txt).I renamed the .csv file to .tct. From another suggestion I have an Execute Process task where I have created a file that says

```
COPY /B E:\Conversion\PlanSource\"Plansource IA Record Out.txt" + E:\Conversion\PlanSource\"II Sample Records Out.txt" "Plansource II Records.txt"
```

The file is named `Make Complete Output File.bat`

The `Execute Process Task` always bombs out. Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Dick

Comment: What error message is the task giving you when it fails?

Comment: Error: 0xC0029151 at Execute Process Task, Execute Process Task: In Executing "E:\Conversion\PlanSource\Make Complete Output File.bat" "" at "", The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".

Comment: When I want to create a .csv file with header or trailers (usually with a summary of the file like totals) I use script component. Its very straightforward and requires just a basic knowledge of C#. If you are interested in this method let me know.

Comment: In my experience, .bat files do not like having spaces in their names. Try removing the spaces from the .bat file name (keep the double quotes for paths with spaces which are used inside the .bat)

Comment: Hi, I replaced the spaces with underscores (Make_Complete_Output_File.bat) but still get the same result

Comment: I'm trying a different tack so am closing this question and will ask another one. Thanks all.